# Xcode how to split substring in two substrings

Tags: nsstring, nsarray, substring

I have a `NSString`. This `NSString` is split in different parts with `";"`.

I split this `NSString` in 2 substrings (with `[componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]`)

Now, I have a substring, with `[componentsSeparatedByString:@";"]`, in a `NSArray`.
In this substring I have (sometimes but not always !) a `","`.

When I have a `","` I want to spilt my substring in two "sub-substrings" and use this two sub-subtrings...

How can I do that ?

Thanks for your answers.

**EDIT :**

Hi @Alladinian, thanks for ur answer. 
That's a loop I need, I think. I want to add new contact to iPhone address book (First name and Last name) with QRCode.

My `NSString` looks like :

`NSString *_name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", code.contact];`

My substring looks like:

`NSArray *subStrings = [code.contact componentsSeparatedByString:@";"];`

In my `NSString`, I have (perhaps but not always) a `","` I need two different outputs : one for first name and one for last name.

I know how to add first name and last name separated by `","` but I don't know what to do if I have only a first name. Have only a first name crash my app...

For now, to skirt problem, I send Fist name and Last name in Fist name field... But it's not perfect for my sake.

Comment: Do you need to store all these substrings in some meaningful way, or just looking for a loop to process them on the fly? In other words, what should the expected output look like?

Comment: And perhaps show a sample input

Comment: Hi Alladibian, hi Martin R, thanks for your answers. EDIT is in question. Thanks for help !

Comment: Do you mean you're creating new contacts where first name and last name are put in the first name field?

Comment: Why not just use componentsSeparatedByString: again?

Comment: Yes @nielsbot, that's what I mean.

Comment: I tried use "componentsSeparatedByString" again, but crash... "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'"

Comment: You need to check the result of componentsSeparatedByString. If count == 1, there's only one string, so can must not ask for array[1].

Comment: What are the pieces separated by ";", and what are the pieces separated by ",". Can you tell us the format of the string?

Comment: string format looks like : "MECARD:N:Jony,Ive;ORG:Apple; ..." / But sometimes, string format looks like : "MECARD:N:Jony;ORG:Apple; ..." or "MECARD:N:Jony Ive;ORG:Apple; ...". May I try with something like : "if ([name componentsSeparatedByString:@","]) {" ?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here's some code you can use. You can't just use `componentsSeparatedByString` for the name because there are 4 cases:

- no comma: assume just first name "first"
- comma, but no last name ", first"
- comma, but no first name "last, "
- comma, both: "last, first"

code:

```
NSString * mecardString = ...your string...

if ( [ mecardString hasPrefix:@"MECARD:" ] ) // is it really a card string? (starts with 'MECARD:')
{
    mecardString = [ mecardString substringFromIndex:[ @"MECARD:" length ] ] ;  // remove MECARD: from start

    NSString * firstName = nil ;
    NSString * lastName = nil ;

    NSArray * components = [ mecardString componentsSeparatedByString:@";" ] ;
    for( NSString * component in components ) // process all parts of MECARD string
    {
        NSString * lcString = [ component lowercaseString ] ;
        if ( [ lcString hasPrefix:@"n:" ] )
        {
            // handle name ("N:")
            NSRange commaRange = [ lcString rangeOfString:@"," ] ;
            if ( commaRange.location == NSNotFound )
            {
                firstName = lcString ;
            }
            else
            {
                firstName = [ lcString substringFromIndex:NSMaxRange( commaRange  ) ] ;
                lastName = [ lcString substringToIndex:commaRange.location ] ;
            }

            NSCharacterSet * whitespaceCharSet = [ NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet ] ;
            firstName = [ firstName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharSet ] ;
            lastName = [ firstName stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:whitespaceCharSet ] ;
        }
        else if  ( lcString hasPrefix:@"sound:" )
        {
            // handle name ("SOUND:")
        }
            // ... write code handle other parts of MECARD... (NICKNAME, BDAY, URL, etc)
        else
        {
            // handle unknown case here
        }
    }

    // you have names here
}
```